# Using of with at the end of a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, american-english

There is a commonly used sentence, "*let's get it over with.*"

I could also say, "*let's get it over.*"
In many sentences, I have seen the use of "with" at the end. Does it make any difference to the meaning?  Eg. "*I just wanted to get over with*"

Comment: Re your last sentence, you cannot say "to get over with*. There has to be an object - even if it is the preposition "it". So you need *to get **it** over with*.

Comment: I'm not familiar with "let's get it over". It always has "...with". Could be a British thing though. I'm Canadian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually an idiomatic composite verb: ***to get (something) over with***. It is used for things which you are obliged to do, but are not going to enjoy, and anxious to put the experience behind you as soon as possible.

If for example you have to have an unpleasant medical procedure - you may want it sooner rather than later so you can ***get it over with*** and go back to enjoying life without losing any more sleep.

Comment: Thanks. I got that part. It's a phrase or idiom. So if I don't put `with` at the end, does that make wrong English. Example: There is some task that the class teacher is pushing everyone to do. And I ask my friend for assistance and say I want to get it over. Is that correct, or should I add `with` at the end

Comment: @rohit It is certainly not incorrect - and is often said in that way - without "with". But adding "with" seems to me to give it a little bit extra emphasis.